# Why do my divs not appear within my main div?

Tags: html, css

I have a main container div and all my other divs are within this main container div. However, I'm seeing that my header is not appearing within my main container, why is that?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.cartcontainer {
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="mid-nav">
      <span class="logo-main">Lifeline's Supplies</span><br>
      <span class="logo-sub">Fashion & Sports Outlet</span>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="cartcontainer">
    <h3 class="CartTitle">My Cart</h3>
    <hr class="CartSeparator">
  </div>
</div>
```

[How the structure is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC2GK.png)

Comment: I do not get the same structure in your screenshot when I copy paste your code.

Answer (score 2):

`position: fixed` elements are removed from the document flow into a new stacking context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position check the docs on the `fixed` value. This shouldn't be a problem though, it's just a style consideration, on the DOM it's inside it's original parent.

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block. (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
>
> This value always creates a new stacking context. In printed documents, the element is placed in the same position on every page.

Comment: Ahh I understand, thank you, I was a bit concerned when I checked it and saw my header wasn't inside the main container.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
.container{
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

instead of

```
.container{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```